# Subir simbolos de depuración nativos ¿Cómo los genero?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

He creado una aplicación, pero cuando la subo a la Play console obtengo lo siguiente:
**"Cargar símbolos de depuración nativos"**

[image: Simbolos nativos]

Ya intenté probar soluciones como esta: Cómo agregar símbolos de depuración a build.gradle

o el de la documentación oficial: [https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=es-419#zippy=%2Cnativo-genera-un-archivo-de-símbolos-de-depuración](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=es-419#zippy=%2Cnativo-genera-un-archivo-de-s%C3%ADmbolos-de-depuraci%C3%B3n)

Pero cuando agrego las líneas a **build.gradle** no se genera ninguna carpeta **"native-debug-symbols"**

**build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 29
            defaultConfig {
                vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
                applicationId "com.adivina.quiz"
                minSdkVersion 19
                ndkVersion "22.0.7026061"
                targetSdkVersion 29
                versionCode 7
                versionName "1.2"
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
                multiDexEnabled true
                ndk {
                    debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
                }

            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-new.pro'
                }
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
            implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
            implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
            implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
            implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
            implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
            implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'
            implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
            implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
                exclude module: 'httpclient'
            }
            implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
            implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
            implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
            implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
        }
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
      repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
      }

      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
      }

    }

    allprojects {
      repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
          url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

      }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradesco su ayuda, soy nuevi en esto de las app.

Answer (score 1):

Es un poco tarde pero dejo la respuesta para otros con la misma duda. Si generas un App Bundle lo único que tienes que hacer es poner la siguiente línea en el **`build.gradle`** de tu aplicación:

```
android.defaultConfig.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'
```

Automáticamente cuando generas en *App Bundle* te incluye toda la información.

Saludos.